# how to import large datasets to mysql - the right way?

Tags: mysql, import, bulkinsert, mysqlimport

I have a 400MB *.sql file which is a dump from a MySQL database. I now want to import this to a new database. I used phpmyadmin but it breaks after a few minutes because it cannot handle such large dataset (max file size limit is reached). So I used the following:

logged in via SSH.
selected the database via mysql tool.
command: source mybackup.sql

Now the queries run but it is running over 3 hours now. What is wrong or does it really take so long?

Thanks,
WorldSignia

Comment: What type are your tables? InnoDB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mysql databaseName < mybackup.sql
```

That is as fast as it gets, I think.

Comment: Only comment that 400MB on SQL code is an enormous load of data. It should take time so don't worry about this.

Comment: Lifesaver, thanks!

FWIW, I had to update this line `max_allowed_packet = 64M` in MySQL's my.ini file (my.cnf on some systems I think). It was defaulted to 1M, my file was 3.5M, so it could have been 8M (instead of 64M) and still worked, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not done already, you can use `set autocommit=0` to turn off autocommit before you import. Otherwise InnoDB will `COMMIT` after every `INSERT` statement. It may help some.

You can also turn off secondary unique keys and foreign keys as well to help. See this link for more ideas:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html